# Any [helpers] for putting the [helper] out of its misery?

Tags: discussion, support, burninate-request, meta-tags

Just stumbled across some [helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helpers) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26793640).

Looking myself, there's also a lonely [helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helper) who left the crowd.

Can we please exterminate them?

(The tags are very vague and meta, and they just cry out for it.
1500 Questions all together, and they are all over the place.)

Comment: 1,042 tagged questions.  That's going to take awhile.  What's the harm in just leaving it?

Comment: Actually 1511, just looked. And there is absolutely no focus/purpose to them, so outright deletion of the tag would be best. (The harm is that people will tag with it, thinking they got an approprite tag, and not go looking for one.)

Comment: Only 1511 edits needed.  You're going to need an army.  Seriously, isn't there some better use of people's time?

Comment: What would happen to a question that had just one tag and that tag was deleted like the OP suggests?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why delete *any* tag with that kind of thinking?

Comment: @RobertHarvey "isn't there some better use of peoples time?" - that's why this is a burninate request, not a manual retag request. I'd recommend burnination and blacklisting.

Comment: Kill it with [tag:fire] (see what I did there? :-)).

Comment: I think there are probably tons of tags like this.  If I look at tags for questions I've responded to, I see all kinds of goofy tags, like [meta-tag:Data]. If that's not generic, I don't know what is.  I think we just have to hope folks end up with appropriate tags as well.

Comment: @cybermonkey ... yeah, I see.

Comment: @l4mpi: **All burninate requests are manual retags.**  There aren't any tools that anyone has (including moderators) that can make a tag magically disappear.  SE has such tools, but observe how many burninate requests were actually handled by SE in the last six months (hint: I can count them on one hand, and have several fingers left over).

Comment: @l4mpi: Blacklisting is dev-only as well, and is reserved only for the most egregious tags.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: See my two comments above.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sounds like SE should get that interface built and expose it to mods (more than one mod required to destroy a popular tag, of course).

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the questions, it seems like "Helper" actually is the correct terminology for [meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor).  (According to comments, a new [meteor-helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-helper) tag has been created and added to the intersection of [meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor) and [helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helpers).  So that's dealt with.)

And all (that I saw) of the rest came from someone typing a sentence `help me frob blah pls` into keywords, and the system suggesting "helpers" as the closest match to "help".

A couple of the questions should be using [helpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helpfile) instead, because they discussed parsing/viewing/browsing help files.  Again, someone probably typed "help" in the tags and it expanded, although this time they actually did mean it as a keyword not a sentence.

It seems like "help" ought to be a blacklisted tag, not a missing tag.  Because having it expand to *any* suggestion, [helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helpers) or otherwise, leads consistently to wrong outcomes.

Comment: in the context of that meteor tag, it would be preferable to refer it as [tag:meteor-helper]

Comment: @gnat: Why, if Meteor is the only environment using the word "helper"?  It doesn't solve anything, as long as throw-a-sentence-in-tags-including-*help* gets auto-expanded to anything.  Instead of moving the expansion target, we need to stop the expansion altogether.

Comment: if users will be blocked from using tag helper at all, this would be indeed so. I mentioned rename only for the case if blacklisting won't happen

Comment: "helper" isn't self-descriptive enough to be allowed. There are many things that use "helper", wizards and the like, which aren't related in any way.

Comment: @gnat: It's not the tag `helper` (or helpers) that needs to be blocked, it's the suggestion `helper` when the user types "please help me"

Comment: Perhaps the [tag:helper] should be changed to [tag:meteor-helper] instead.

Comment: @cybermonkey: gnat already said that.  Which is fine, if `helper` is actually ambiguous.  Based on the list of questions, though, it seems like there's helper in the context of meteor, and there's mistagged, probably by the suggestion mechanism.  No ambiguity.

Comment: The suggestion mechanism is still nothing more than a *suggestion* mechanism, right? Meaning that people still need to manually accept tags? If that's the case, renaming to `meteor-helper` would help a *lot*, I'd think, since I would expect even people who don't understand the tag system to realize that "help me frob my foobars" has nothing to do with anything called "Meteor".

Comment: @KyleStrand: It won't help at all.  Sure, it will keep "help me" in the tags from becoming [tag:helpers], but it just moves the problem around.  Creating a bunch of invalid [tag:helpfile] tags instead is not a solution to the issue we have with [tag:helpers].  Remember that suggestions get auto-accepted as you keep typing.

Comment: So, to summarize: You found redeeming value for [tag:helper] in the context of [tag:meteor]. Well, I'll accept that, but that's only 15 questions in both tags together, so less than 1%. (Retagged all to [tag:meteor-helper] as suggested (Still needs a tag-wiki), because the tag is not descriptive enough and they were crowded out.) Regarding banning help and autocompletion of it to something else, be my guest.

Comment: @BenVoigt meteor isn't the only technology to use this name. MVC in .NET does, too, and it's an equally useless name there.

Comment: And CakePHP! And Ruby on Rails! And my AX!

Comment: @jpmc26: I know nothing about meteor, but after looking at code snippets in questions tagged helpers, [tag:meteor-helper] seems to be on an equal level to an interface or a listener in other platforms.  So while in other places it may be useless, it seems like a bigger thing in meteor.  Now that those are retagged, is there anything left that isn't a mistag?

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm sorry, I'm still not quite clear on what you're saying. What, exactly, is going to cause the creation of "a bunch of invalid helpfile tags"? Are you just saying that since "helpfile" is closer to "help" than "meteor-helper" is, changing the `helper` tag to `meteor-helper` would cause `helpfile` to be suggested where currently `helper` is suggested?

Comment: @KyleStrand: Yes.  Cleaning up this tag, without also addressing the autocompletion *help*->(whatever), is just going to perpetuate the problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt And is it also the case that typing "help" in the tag box, followed by a space, auto-completes to the `help<whatever>` tag (where `<whatever>` is currently `file`) for users who don't have enough rep to make their own tags? (I tried to just test this on my own, but for me this turns into a new `help` tag, since I have the tag-creation privilege.)

Comment: Helpers could refer to Handlebar helpers but that should be its own tag.

Answer (score 10):

For those pointing out that "helper" is a correct terminology in some frameworks, templating libraries, etc., I acknowledge that, but I doubt the value in an actual **tag** devoted to this particular mechanism. It makes more sense for it to be tagged by the framework/library, where it will garner some attention. The fact it's related to whatever the framework/library calls a "helper" doesn't seem significant enough to warrant a full tag. Additionally, the name is so utterly nondescriptive that it could mean virtually anything depending on the framework/library, and thus adds almost zero value to the question as a tag.

While I'm usually cautious about the following argument against tags, I think it actually makes sense given how vague the name is. You can't be a "helper" expert because "helper" is so ill defined. Certainly, this also means that the [helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helper) tag can't stand on its own; it would need additional tags, making its value even more dubious.

I'm all for burnination.

Comment: You could say the same for `interface` or `delegate` or `pointer`.  They apply to a lot of different frameworks.  Yet they serve mostly the same function across the gamut, and so experience from one can translate to the others.  Perhaps that isn't true of frameworks using [tag:helpers].

Comment: Help the [tag:helper] helpers help you use helpers? Ugh. That's one of those words that starts to look weird/stupid when you look at it too much.

Comment: @BenVoigt, `interface` and `pointer` mean the same thing no matter what language you use them in - they come with differing implementation but the same conceptual background. With helpers this is not the case. The only common ground behind things tagged helper is their auxiliary nature.

Comment: Tags are to attract people to questions who might have domain knowledge to help answer them.  The word 'helper' doesn't tell anybody if they know enough to solve the question, but the name of a language and framework being used (even if 'helper' is the specific name of a module or library) definitely do.  For more specifics, descriptive question names can be used.

Comment: @Noamyoungerm, [tag:interface] has an extremely vague name. It could, on its face, refer to interfaces as they exist in Java, or to human-computer interfaces, or to APIs, or to ABIs, or any number of other things.