# Merge tags: [asp.net-core-tag-helpers] and [tag-helpers]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

[asp.net-core-tag-helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-tag-helpers) and [tag-helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-helpers) have identical descriptions and an almost equal number of questions tagged with them. The technology is specific to ASP.NET Core, so I'm not sure which tag is better to keep, but either way, it seems like clutter to have both.

Comment: All ASP.NET related tags start with `asp.net-`, so `asp.net-core-tag-helpers` should be kept

Comment: Relevant discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276259/1394393. So sick of Microsoft giving everything stupidly general names.

Comment: @jpmc26 Not sure how that's relevant or why Tag Helper is a stupidly general name.

Comment: @jpmc26 Tag Helper is perfectly fine name.

Comment: Or we introduce a helper tag for the tag helpers...

Comment: To anyone interested: now that [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349547/merge-tags-viewcomponents-asp-net-viewcomponents-and-razor-viewcomponent) is done, I will start with this request. Currently: 18 tagged [tag:razor-taghelpers] and 266 tagged [tag:tag-helpers]

Comment: Done with [tag:razor-taghelpers] and [tag:tag-helpers] went down to 256

Comment: Both tags have the exact same description (minus typo / spelling). Any chance those two can be merged?

Comment: I have resumed this today, retagged some 80 questions already. It's down to 200 now. @Métoule Wanna help out?

Comment: just found [asp.net-core-tag-helpers] 327 and [tag-helpers] 354 questions. 50 questions with both tags.

Answer (score -1):

Tag helpers were introduced in ASP.NET vNEXT (working title) / 5, later released as ASP.NET Core.

[Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

> Tag Helpers enable server-side code to participate in creating and rendering HTML elements in Razor files.

So the ASP.NET Core part is always implied when talking about tag helpers. I think simpler is better. Either keep [tag-helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-helpers) or use [razor-tag-helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor-tag-helpers). Don't put ASP.NET Core in it.